# Google Maps API - Get Coordinates of address

Tags: google-maps

I would like to convert addresses into long/lat.

Is there any way to do this without using JavaScript? Because in my case there is no need to *display* anything since the conversion is in the background.

Answer (score 297, accepted):

What you are looking for is called [Geocoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geocoding).

Google provides a [Geocoding Web Service](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/geocoding/) which should do what you're looking for. You will be able to do geocoding on your server.

JSON Example:

> http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=1600+Amphitheatre+Parkway,+Mountain+View,+CA

XML Example:

> http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=1600+Amphitheatre+Parkway,+Mountain+View,+CA

---

**Edit:**

Please note that this is now a deprecated method and you must provide your own Google API key to access this data.

Comment: @n00b: I initially mis-read your question. You're looking for Geocoding, not Reverse Geocoding. Nevertheless, you can still do it with the Google Web Services API.

Comment: The link says the `sensor` parameter is no longer required.

Comment: ok its work but now i want to search address for only USA country but its give me all over the world search data return can u give me a solution for particular country

Comment: @PareshHirpara Shouldn't you have to insert `United+States` inside the  address parameter? ;-)

Answer (score 20):

Althugh you asked for Google Maps API, I suggest an **open source, working, legal, free** and **crowdsourced** API by [Open street maps](https://www.openstreetmap.org/)

> https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search?q=Mumbai&format=json

[Here is the API documentation](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Nominatim) for reference.

Edit: It looks like there are discrepancies occasionally, at least in terms of postal codes, when compared to the Google Maps API, and the latter seems to be more accurate. This was the case when validating addresses in Canada with the Canada Post search service, however, it might be true for other countries too.

Comment: First of all - thank you for suggesting this option, too. :)
In my case I was looking for the postal code of an address based on street number, street name, city and province (in Canada). However, it turns out there's a discrepancy in what the Google Maps API and the Open Street Maps API returned.
For example, for the address 20 Toronto Street, Toronto, ON, they returned different postal codes and the one returned by the Google Maps API is the same as the one that the search on Canada Post's website returns. I tested it with two other addresses too and there were discrepancies again.

Comment: @NikolayD It looks like there are errors in the crowd sourced data. Go with Google Maps then! [Suggest your inputs as an edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/49854589/edit) to my answer please

Comment: @Dantalian What is the definition of address number?

Comment: Sorry, i meant street number

Answer (score 9):

Geocoding through `Javascript`:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding

Answer (score 3):

A Nuget solved my problem:Geocoding.Google 4.0.0. 
Install it so not necessary to write extra classes etc.

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Geocoding.Google/