# Get Google map coordinates on save in Sitecore?

Tags: sitecore

I have a Sitecore 6 solution where an editor can create an item and enter an adress in a field. This adress is then used frontend to make a lookup on a Google Map.

But instead of having to make a lookup in GMap each time the page is loaded in the frontend, i would like to get the coordinates of the entered adress once the editor has saved the item, and then save these coordinates to another field on the same item.

How could i do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to create an event handler that subscribes to the item:saved event. http://sdn.sitecore.net/Articles/API/Using%20Events.aspx

To retrieve the lat/lng from the address you can use the Google geocoding web service [Google Maps API - Get Coordinates of address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3652951/google-maps-api-get-coordinates-of-address)

Comment: Exactly what I was going to suggest.