# in google map url is ll the longitude latitude ? if not than how to get it from the url

Tags: php, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

the example url is :
https://maps.google.com.sa/maps?q=FedEx+Office+-+Ahsa+St.,+Al+Ahsa+Street,+Riyadh&hl=en&ll=24.693415,46.732444&spn=0.003007,0.004823&sll=24.266906,45.09835&sspn=24.566344,39.506836&oq=FedEx+Office+-+Ahsa+St.,&t=h&z=18&iwloc=A

is the ll para longitude latitude position ?
if not than how to get it ?

Answer (score 0):

It think you are trying to get coordinates from an address if that is the case this question is a possible duplicate of [Google Maps API - Get Coordinates of address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3652951/google-maps-api-get-coordinates-of-address)

Comment: right now I'm doing it with google maps api but the prob is, it takes too much time as I have to do it for around 200 url's So is it possible to get the longitude latitude position from the url ?? ...