# Geocoding without use of visual components

Tags: delphi, geocode, gmlib

I have been using the GMLib for Google Maps operations for some years now without any problems and have made some interesting things if I must say so.
But now I am working on another project where I have a full address and needs to geocode that, but I don't need to show it on a map since I just need the latitude and longitude to calculate a QRA locator (it is a system of map grids used by HAM operators all over the world)

I think I could speed up the process by not using a map since it takes time to load every time.

Are there any components or libraries that could help me or isn't it possible to do at all.

Comment: Is the following what you are asking [Google Maps API - Get Coordinates of address](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3652951/google-maps-api-get-coordinates-of-address)

Comment: Also, [take a look at this](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Nominatim). No Delphi examples (as not in my previous comment), so you would have to figure out how to use these services.

Comment: Be careful with that, because you can't use the geocode service without displaying results on a Google map!!! See [polices of geocoding api](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/policies)

Comment: OK - I don't want to be violating any policies so I will have ti stick with the way I do it for now. Maybe some day I will find another solution that could add a bit of speed.